# C Alphabetical Array Sort Either Way

Tags: c, arrays, linux, sorting

I do have a bit of a problem with sorting chars in C. In case I want to sort an array in alphabetical order from z to a, it works just fine. When I try to do the opposite, from a to z, it doesnt work.. I could use some help, thanks ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char s1[10],a;
    int i,t;
    printf("enter a set to sort: ");
    scanf("%s",s1);
    t=1;
//  printf("%d length of set",strlen(s1));
    while (t==1)
    {
//      printf("a\n");
        t=0;
        for (i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++)
            {
                if (s1[i]<s1[i+1])
                {
//              printf("s");
                t=1;
                a=s1[i+1];
                s1[i+1]=s1[i];
                s1[i]=a;
                }
            }
    }
    printf("%s sorted",s1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use only 1 loop then it would not sort all combinations. so use bubble sorts logic.

```
while (t==1)
    {
//      printf("a\n");
        t=0;
        for (i=0;i<strlen(s1)-1;i++)
            {
              for(j=0;j<strlen(s1)-1-i;j++)
              {
                if (s1[j]<s1[j+1])
                {
//              printf("s");
                t=1;
                a=s1[j+1];
                s1[j+1]=s1[j];
                s1[j]=a;
                }
              }
            }
    }
```

Comment: @user3395711 ok. read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to know about using stackoverflow.accept one right answer and up vote any usefull answers

Answer (score 1):

Here's a big problem:

```
if (s1[i]<s1[i+1])
```

This will compare the last character in the string with the string terminator. So you will sort your string *including* the string terminator, which is not quite what you want.

Comment: it wont, because "i" will reach a max value of "lenght - 1" thanks to "i<strlen(s1)", am I correct? If the length of a string is lets say 5, "i" will reach a max value of 4

Comment: dejvid@dejvid-Aspire-V5-431 ~/Desktop/C/test $ ./test
enter set to sort: abcdefg
7 length of set
gfedcba sorted

Comment: @user3395711 That check, `i < strlen(s1)` will make sure that `i` is valid and within range, but then you use `i + 1` which for the last character will be the same as `strlen(s1)`, i.e. one beyond the last "real" character in the string, and in fact is the string terminator.

Comment: Well, of course this generally is important, in this case it doesn't matter, because `0` is less than any sane character input and... Oh, okay, I thought that he was having problems while sorting in descending order. Maybe you should clarify why it does work, accidentally, while sorting in descending order, and why it would just be an empty string after sorting in ascending order, which is the main reason why he/she's asking this question in the first place @Joachim :D

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, the ideal way to do this in C would be this:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>         // qsort
#include <ctype.h>          // toupper
#include <stdio.h>          // printing

int chrcmp (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  char ch1 = *(const char*)obj1;
  char ch2 = *(const char*)obj2;

  ch1 = toupper(ch1);       // remove case-sensitivity
  ch2 = toupper(ch2);

  return ch1 - ch2;         // integer promotion will make this int implicitly
}


int main()
{
  char str[] = "Sort letters and symbols alphabetically";

  puts(str);

  qsort (str,                // the array to sort
         sizeof(str)-1,      // the number of items in the array (minus nullterm)
         sizeof(char),       // the size of each item
         chrcmp);            // comparison function

  puts(str);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Sort letters and symbols alphabetically
    aaaabbcdeeehilllllmnooprrSsssttttyy
```